# Storing methods needed in all components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a universal app I'm developing for learning purposes. I'm managing the state of my app with Redux, so all my data will be available there. But I want to create some methods that I'm going to use in all my components. The problem is: where should I store this methods?

Adding them to a parent component and passing the methods as props doesn't seem very useful, because this is one of the things that Redux tries to solve. And I'm pretty sure that Redux is not a place for storing methods.

I know I can create a class in a file somewhere, export it, add some methods to it, and when I want to use one method in a component I can call this file, create an instance of the class and call the needed method; but this doesn't look very react to me…

Is there a right way to create methods available for all components?

Comment: Using Redux, you should use actions and reducers, check: https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers, and https://redux.js.org/basics/actions

Comment: "But I want to create some methods that I'm going to use in all my components." could you plz provide an example of such an universal method? Does it have to be a method (has access to component instance)?

Comment: One example would be authentication tasks. I'm using a Json Web Token stored in a cookie, and for loging out I need some components to access to a `logout()` method. Route components will need to check if the user is validated or not, and these methods should be shared between them.

Comment: i agree with @DamianPeralta, a logout method should make use of actions and reducers, other methods/ functions unrelated to performing a specific redux/ store action could be held in a helper file and you can `import` them. If a certain context is needed you can use `.bind` or `.call`

Comment: Ok, so all the methods performing tasks that modifies the state of the applications are stored in actions. But I have a problem: this is a universal app, and I need the library `react-cookie` to store cookies both in client and server; the problem is that the cookies provided by this library is only accesible inside the components, so I wouldn't be able to create a cookie in a Redux action. How should I solve this problem?

Comment: "One example would be authentication tasks." Usually this is moved to redux. Login/logout are action creators, token is stored in store, some middleware is used to add token to every request,  "check if user is valid" is selector that checks if there is token in store.

Comment: @Nikita `withCookies(Component)` is a HOC, and will add what you need to the props of a component you need the data in.  I would recommend reading into what HOCs are and how to use them.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I have been thinking about this possibility, and as I see it this token can not be moved to the store because is an universal app, and I would loose it at every reload. I could save the token in a universal cookie for both server and client with `react-cookie`, but I would end up duplicating things.
Whats the usual solution for universal apps?

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success sharing functions between components using an approach similar to the following. I'm not sure this approach will solve your specific use case with regards to cookies, however.

These functions can be stored anywhere and imported wherever required. They accept a component as their first argument, then return a function that operates on the component passed in.

Indicative, untested code follows.

```
// An event handler than can be shared between multiple components
const handleChange = component => event => component.setState({ value: event.target.value });

class ComponentOne extends PureComponent {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.value}
        <input onChange={handleChange(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ComponentTwo extends PureComponent {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.value}
        <input onChange={handleChange(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```